# extracting frames from a mp4.file

Tags: android, mp4, javacv

i want to open a .mp4 file, so that i can access each frame.
I tried to do it using javacv, but it didnt work.(see code below)
Does anyone know why it didnt work or how else i could achieve my goal?

i tried to call

```
string path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "Test";
opencv_videoio.VideoCapture cap = new opencv_videoio.VideoCapture(path + File.separator + "test.mp4");
```

but then `cap.isOpend()` returns `false`. I have set the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`(which includes READ)

Comment: By extracting frames, what does this mean? Do you want to have thumbnails for every frame of that video ?

Comment: i want to access every frame as some sort of picture like a opencv Mat or a Bitmap

Comment: you can use then `ffmpeg`

Comment: do you mean ffmpeg-java or Jffmpeg? And where can i get it for windows?

Comment: ok i got it working using [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.de/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)